# Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers not able to run

Tags: eclipse

I've downloaded and exracted the files to c:\ but when I go to run it I get this error message

Java Virtual Machine Launcher

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.

and another window which says:

Eclipse

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-add-modules= =java.se.ee
-Dosgi.required JavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1 1.3.0.v20130327-1440.j
ar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700\splash.b
mp
-launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.
1.200.v20140116-2212\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1 1.3.0.v20130327-1440.j
ar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 198c_ec
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-add-modules= =java.se.ee
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar`
```

This happens when I try to run the eclipse application file.

Comment: That looks like Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) which is now 10 years and 23 releases old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using a very old and unsupported release that's not compatible with Java releases from this decade, and definitely untested on modern O.S. releases. Start over with a fresh directory and download from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers .